# Set Excel protect properties From HTA

Tags: vba, vbscript, hta

How do I use the following in a vbscript on HTA.

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

If I try the same with ":=" , it throws page error.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way. I Inserted the required code into VB code module of the object Excel.
Something like below.

```
With myReport.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, _ 
    "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" & Chr(13) & _
    " ProtectMe(1)" & vbNewLine & _
    "End Sub" & vbNewLine & _
    "Sub ProtectMe(Status)" & vbNewLine & _
    "   Dim mySheet As Worksheet" & vbNewLine & _
    "   Dim myPassword " & vbNewLine & _
    "   myPassword = ""IamGenius""" & vbNewLine & _
    "   For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" & vbNewLine & _
    "       mySheet.Protect Password:=myPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, _" & vbNewLine & _
    "       Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, _" & vbNewLine & _
    "       AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True" & vbNewLine & _
    "       mySheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells" & vbNewLine & _
    "   Next mySheet" & vbNewLine & _
    "End Sub"          
End With
```

Thanks,
Anand:)

Answer (score 0):

To 'port' VBA code like

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

to VBScript to be used in .HTAs (host: mshta.exe) or .VBSs (host c/wscript.exe) you have to

1. Create an Excel.Application COM object
2. Use that and it's Workbook/Worksheet collections to drill down to the object you want to call the method on
3. Convert the named arguments of VBA to positional arguments of VBScript (based on the docs for that method)
4. Define the xlXXXX constants

Start your research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the concept of objects and then calling the method. I was expecting it to be something like this, but it did not work.

    `objWorkSheet.Protect.DrawingObjects=xlConstant`
    `objWorkSheet.Protect.Contents=xlConstant`
    `objWorkSheet.Protect.Scenarios=xlConstant`
    `objWorkSheet.Protect.AllowFiltering=xlConstant`